# Dropping second model name in nested resource route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-resources

I'm using slugs for IDs, so wanting URLs like /songs/radiohead/karma-police instead of /artists/radiohead/songs/karma-police.

Slugs can be achieved with:

```
def to_param
  slug
end
```

But how is there any way to drop the model name - "songs" - from the standard RESTful URL?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Default segment name in rails resources routing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182040/default-segment-name-in-rails-resources-routing)

Comment: Didn't see that when searching, but I think this is sufficiently different as it's about retaining the first name and dropping the second, whereas that question is vice-versa. Nested routing being the tricky thing it is, it's a separate enough problem to make a separate question a useful resource. I'll update the title to reflect the difference.

Comment: Confirmed this works in Rails 3.1. If you can answer the question with resources :songs, :path => '', I'll accept it.

Comment: I got an even better one for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the path segment by passing the `:path` option to your `resources` call.

```
resources :songs, path: "songs/:artist_id"
```

this will generate these routes

```
      songs GET    /songs/:artist_id(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"songs"}
            POST   /songs/:artist_id(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"songs"}
   new_song GET    /songs/:artist_id/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"songs"}
  edit_song GET    /songs/:artist_id/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"songs"}
       song GET    /songs/:artist_id/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"songs"}
            PUT    /songs/:artist_id/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"songs"}
            DELETE /songs/:artist_id/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"songs"}
```

Comment: That actually is a better one :). Thanks. In case anyone else is wondering, the routes declaration here is *not* nested; just declare this as a separate route.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your `routes.rb` and it should work.

```
match 'artists/:artist_id/:id' => 'songs#show', :as => 'artist_song'
```

Make sure if you do the `:as` that the other routes don't take precedence over this one.

Then check out this [Routing `match` reference](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Base.html#method-i-match)

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't generate URLs this way though. ie artist_song_url  will still generate both model names.

Comment: The other question linked by @edgerunner is a better answer. Check it out